# How to get the Percentage of a Column based on a Condition? Python

Tags: python, pandas, percentage

I want to calculate the percentage of my Products column according to the occurrences per related Country. I would greatly appreciate your help.

Here is what I did so far,
I calculated my new dataframe with this code:

```
gb = data1.groupby(['Country', 'Products']).size()
df = gb.to_frame(name = 'ProductsCount').reset_index()
df
```

Which gives me something that look like this:

```
   Countries    Products     ProductsCount
0  Country 1     Product 1     5
1  Country 1     Product 2     31
2  Country 2     Product 1     2
3  Country 2     Product 2     1
```

Note: I have a couple of thousands rows of output.

My goal is to get the percentage per each products according to the country directly without calculating the ['ProductsCount'], like this:

```
   Countries    Products     Percentage
0  Country 1     Product 1     0.138
1  Country 1     Product 2     0.861
2  Country 2     Product 1     0.667
3  Country 2     Product 2     0.333
```

Otherwise If I can't get the the output to show only the %, then I would like something like this:

```
   Countries    Products     ProductsCount   Products%
0  Country 1     Product 1     5                0.138
1  Country 1     Product 2     31               0.861
2  Country 2     Product 1     2                0.667
3  Country 2     Product 2     1                0.333
```

I managed to calculate only the % according to the whole dataset using this code:

```
df['Products%'] = df.ProductsCount/len(df.Country)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well, what is the rule that tells you, for example, that the result should be `0.138` given `5` products, or whatever? What is it a percentage *of*? When you say "I managed to calculate only the % according to the whole dataset using this code", *what is different between that result, and an actual solution to the problem*? I can't understand what it is that you actually need help with.

Comment: What I meant was I managed to calculate the frequency of, say, product 1 on all the entries of my dataset but not grouped per countries. 100% was the whole dataset but I wanted 100% to be the number of times the product occurred per country. @jezrael found the solution to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) with `normalize=True` parameter:

```
df = (data1.groupby('Countries')['Products']
           .value_counts(normalize=True,sort=False)
           .reset_index(name='Percentage'))
print (df)
   Countries   Products  Percentage
0  Country 1  Product 1    0.138889
1  Country 1  Product 2    0.861111
2  Country 2  Product 1    0.666667
3  Country 2  Product 2    0.333333
```

EDIT:

```
df = (data1.groupby('Countries')['Products']
           .value_counts(sort=False)
           .reset_index(name='ProductsCount')
           .assign(Percentage = lambda x: x['ProductsCount'].div(len(x))))
print (df)
```

Comment: What if I want the other columns from the original dataset data1 to show as well?

Comment: @KilliMandjaro - Added answer, or use your solution form question

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I meant in the data1 that I'm actually working with I have other columns not mentioned here. Like Price, Quantity, Gender and so on... How could I also show them?

Comment: @KilliMandjaro - I think you need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47360510/pandas-groupby-and-aggregation-output-should-include-all-the-original-columns-i)

Comment: Would you be able to explain it? I'm new to python, thus I can't figure out how to implement it for my case

Comment: @KilliMandjaro - I think the best should be create new question with sample data, expectedoutput and what you try.