# How to aggregate only one column pandas python 2.7

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I try to aggregate based on one column "col1" like this and keep same value from other columns:

```
df_input 

       col1      col2    col3    col4  
0       ID1      DE      69      min-8     
1       ID1      DZ      69      min-8
2       ID3      DA      54      min-15
3       ID3      AC      54      min-15
4       ID3      RC      54      min-15
5       ID8      UC      2       min-40
6       ID8      TC      2       min-40
7       ID8      VC      2       min-40
8       ID8      WC      2       min-40
9       ID7      XC      4       min-7



df_output 

           col1      col2             col3    col4  
    0       ID1      DE,DZ            69      min-8     
    1       ID3      DA,AC,RC         54      min-15
    2       ID8      UC,TC,VC,WC      2       min-40
    3       ID7      XC               4       min-7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try breaking the below code.

- First, group your dataframe by **col1**, and then perform `.agg` on the grouped object.
- We will then use a `lambda` function on **col2** to get all of it's elements in a `list`
- Let's use the argument `'first'`, to show that we want to keep only the first element of **col3** and **col4**
- Then, reset the index.

```
agg_df = (df.groupby('col1')
      .agg({'col2': lambda x: x.tolist(),'col3':'first','col4':'first'})
      .reset_index())     

print(agg_df)

  col1              col2  col3    col4
0  ID1          [DE, DZ]    69   min-8
1  ID3      [DA, AC, RC]    54  min-15
2  ID7              [XC]     4   min-7
3  ID8  [UC, TC, VC, WC]     2  min-40
```

To then convert **col2** from having it's values stored in a `list` to proper `string`, we can `join` it's elements using a `,`:

```
agg_df['col2'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(str(i) for i in x))

Out[16]: 
0          DE,DZ
1       DA,AC,RC
2             XC
3    UC,TC,VC,WC
Name: col2, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank your for your fast reply and the details of the explanation !!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: I got another question do you know if there is the method when you don't specify the colnames ? I try to join when the value is different and aggregate when the value is identical without specify the colnames ? I don't know if it is possible ?

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand what you mean. Can you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Yes sorry, it is not really clear on my head but I was wondering if we can only specifiy and aggregated value from col1 and the others columns without specify colnames, because I got a big dataframe; But it is ok I just specify for each columns from the dataframe to keep the first element or join elements

Comment: please check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47360510/pandas-groupby-and-aggregation-output-should-include-all-the-original-columns-i. You might find what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Sophods answer, one line of code should resolve your problem

```
df = df.groupby('col1').agg({'col2':lambda x: ",".join(x),'col3':np.mean,'col4':'first'}).reset_index()
```