# How to drop duplicate rows using value_counts and also using a condition that uses the actual value in a column using pandas?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have the following dataframe. I want to group by `a` first. Within each group, I need to do a value count based on `c` and only pick the one with most counts if the value in `c` is not `EMP`. If the value in `c` is `EMP`, then I want to pick the one with the second most counts. If there is no other value than `EMP`, then it should be `EMP` as in the case where a = 4.

```
a        c
1        EMP
1        y
1        y
1        z
2        z
2        z
2        EMP
2        z
2        a
2        a
3        EMP
3        EMP
3        k
4        EMP
4        EMP
4        EMP
```

The expected result would be

```
a        c
1        y
2        z
3        k
4        EMP
```

This is what I have tried so far: I have managed to sort it in the order I need so I could take the first row. However, I cannot figure out how to implement the condition for `EMP` using a lambda function with the `drop_duplicates` function as there is only the `keep=first` or `keep=last` option.

```
df = df.iloc[df.groupby(['a', 'c']).c.transform('size').mul(-1).argsort(kind='mergesort')]
```

**Edit:**

The `mode` solution worked, I have an additional question. My dataframe contains about 50 more columns, and I would like to have all of these columns in the end result as well, with the values corresponding to the rows picked using the mode operation and the first value that occurred for the EMP rows. How would I do that? Is there an easier solution than what is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47360510/pandas-groupby-and-aggregation-output-should-include-all-the-original-columns-i) where you create a dict of functions and pass it to `agg`? Using SQL for this is also fine.

Answer (score 1):

One option could be to remove the EMP, get the [`mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html) per group, then [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) on unique `a` filling with 'EMP':

```
out = (df[df['c'].ne('EMP')]
       .groupby('a', sort=False)['c']
       .apply(lambda g: g.mode()[0])
       .reindex(df['a'].unique(), fill_value='EMP')
       .reset_index()
      )
```

Similar approach using a custom function:

```
def cust_mode(s):
    counts = s.value_counts(sort=False)
    if 'EMP' in counts.index:  # make the EMP count -1
        counts['EMP'] = -1
    return counts.idxmax()

out = df.groupby('a', as_index=False)['c'].agg(cust_mode)
```

Another option would be to perform a custom sort by [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html) and moving the EMP to the top (using [`numpy.lexsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html)), then getting the last value per group ([`groupby.last`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.last.html)):

```
import numpy as np

count = df.merge(df.value_counts().reset_index(name='count'))['count']
out = (df.iloc[np.lexsort([count, df['c'].ne('EMP')])]
         .groupby('a', as_index=False).last()
       )
```

Output:

```
   a    c
0  1    y
1  2    z
2  3    k
3  4  EMP
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work as well:

```
(df.value_counts()
 .reset_index(name = 'count')
 .sort_values('c',key = lambda x: x.eq('EMP'))
 .groupby('a')[['a','c']].head(1)
 .sort_values('a'))
```

Output:

```
   a    c
2  1    y
0  2    z
8  3    k
1  4  EMP
```

Comment: This is more or less equivalent to my `lexsort` approach, sorting first by count (implicitly done by default in `value_counts`), then by EMP status ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
out = df.value_counts(['a', 'c']).reset_index()
pd.concat([
    out.loc[~out.duplicated(['a'], keep=False) & out['c'].eq('EMP')],
    out.loc[out['c'].ne('EMP')].sort_values('count', ascending=False)
    .drop_duplicates('a')])[['a', 'c']]
```

Output:

```
   a    c
1  4  EMP
0  2    z
2  1    y
8  3    k
```